# Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'AndHUD

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am getting this error during compilation . Anybody has any idea how to get come out of it

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'AndHUD, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

File name: 'AndHUD.dll'

```
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)  XamarinForms.QbChat.Android
```

Comment: what have you tried out to fix your issue? Have you looked through NuGet for the AndHUD package and installing it?

Comment: Yes sir ...Got it..Issue resolved.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search through NuGet for the AndHUD package and install it